# Orientation problem with tabbarcontroller + navigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have one TabBarController that has Two tabs. Each tab has one NavigationController in it. Now if the first tab is selected and I rotate the app then shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: gets called of rootViewController of first tab nav controller and thats right but when I select the second tab and then I rotate the device then still the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method of first tab gets called.

I want to layout different tab differently. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tab bar controller can only change to another orientation if the root view controller of each tab supports that orientation. Which makes sense, otherwise a user would somehow switch orientation when she selected another tab.

Answer (score 0):

Override this method and call this method in view will appear.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {
     if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
  {

  }
 }
```